# Xpages view after search

Tags: search, view, xpages

How can I get a column documents from a view after search? I know that with @DbColumn(@DbName(),"viewName",#) I can get the # column documents from the view, but it is not updating after search... The values are the same as before filtered...

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Florin

Answer (score 2):

You could do a search in your view via SSJS and then loop through the entry collection afterwards to fetch the column values, e.g.

```
var view = database.getView("myView");
var col = view.search("searchformula", null, 0);
var ent = col.getFirstEntry();
while(ent!=null){
var colvalue = ent.getColumnValues()[index];
ent = col.getNextEntry(ent);
}
```

Comment: Oliver's right, you'll need to perform the search in SSJS (or Java, if that's your preference). If you set the search property on a dominoView datasource, you are not changing the back-end view accessed via SSJS. You are just filtering the entries in the dominoView Java object that wraps the back-end view, basically telling the dominoView at runtime to perform `view.search("searchformula", null, 0)`. See http://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-xpages-views/ for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I get an error when using     var col = view.search("searchformula", null, 0); Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=16: [TypeError] Error calling method 'search(string, null, number)' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.View [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.View: lotus.domino.View]'... What you mean by "searchformula"? Thanks...